# Encontrar números primos de un número entero

Tags: python

Estoy intentando crear un programa que encuentre los números primos de un número entero. Pero, cuando ejecuto el programa, el resultado no se me imprime.

Este es el código:

```py
def genera_numeros(limite):
    numero = 0
    while numero < limite:
        yield numero+1
devuelve_numeros= genera_numeros(10)


if genera_numeros==10:
    for i in range(11):
        operación = 847%genera_numeros
        if operación != 0:
            print(operación)
```

La respuesta del programa al ejecutarlo es un espacio en blanco.

Comment: `if genera_numeros==10:` estás comparando una función con un número (10)?? Cómo pretendes que eso sea igual? Lee tranquilamente lo que has escrito. Qué quieres comparar? Lo que ha devuelto la función? Eso lo has guardado en `devuelve_numeros`. No entiendo muy bien el concepto de lo que intentas hacer, pero desde luego la comparación de arriba no tiene sentido ninguno, nunca va a entrar a ese `if` y por eso no imprime nada

Answer (score 1):

Analicemos el código, comenzando por estas líneas:

```
def genera_numeros(limite):
    numero = 0
    while numero < limite:
        yield numero+1
```

Esto define una función *generadora* que emite *pretende* emitir los valores 0, 1, 2, ... hasta alcanzar `limite`.

El error está en que nunca modifica el valor de `numero` dentro del `while`, por lo que siempre emite el valor `1`.

La siguiente línea

```
devuelve_numeros= genera_numeros(10)
```

deja en `devuelve_numeros` un objeto de tipo *generador*, algo que se puede usar como iterador en un ciclo, por ejemplo:

```
for i in devuelve_numeros:
    print(i)
```

Este código siempre imprime infinitas líneas de `1`.

Asi se entiende mejor la falla en la siguiente línea:

```
if genera_numeros==10:
```

pues `genera_numeros` es un objeto *generador* y `10` es un objeto entero, por lo que la igualdad no se cumple y el resto del `if` no se ejecuta (y no imprime nada, por tanto):

```
for i in range(11):
    operación = 847%genera_numeros
    if operación != 0:
        print(operación)
```

Esto cubre la causa del problema "no imprime nada".

Al parecer quieres calcular los factores del número 847. Creo que esto puede servirte:

```
def genera_numeros(limite):
    numero = 0
    while numero < limite:
        numero += 1
        yield numero

for i in genera_numeros(847 / 2):
    if 847 % i == 0:
        print(i)
```

Primero soluciona el problema con el generador, incrementando la variable y luego prueba **todos** los posibles divisores de 847 hasta el limite de 847/2.

Dentro del ciclo se limita a examinar el resto de la división de 847 por `i`. Si el resto es cero, entonces `i` es un factor de 847, y se imprime:

```
1
7
11
77
121

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Solución Pythonesca**

```
print(*(i for i in range(1, int(847 / 2)) if 847 % i == 0))
```

produce:

```
1 7 11 77 121

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Me ha servido de mucha ayuda, muchas gracias. De todas maneras, me podrías decir porqué has dividido el 847 entre dos?

Comment: @RodrigoGarciaBaqueroCano Los divisores de un número no primo tienen que ser menores a su raíz cuadrada. Eso es costoso de calcular, entonces se usa la mitad como limite superior, lo que cuesta algunas iteraciones extra.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, de verdad

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, estas buscando los números primos de x numero entero.

**Por ejemplo** : **"Los números primeros que existen del numero x"**

la definición en Wikipedia de números primos es la siguientes:

**"un número primo es un número natural mayor que 1 que tiene únicamente dos divisores positivos distintos: él mismo y el 1"**

Si queremos conocer que números primos existen hasta el numero x debemos calcular entonces salteando el 1:

El Numero 2: Es divisible al 1 y divisible con si mismo (2).

El Numero 3: Es divisible al 1 y divisible con si mismo (3).

**Tanto el 2 y el 3 son Primos porque tienen solo esos dos divisores.**

**En cambio el numero 4:**

El Numero 4: Es divisible al 1, divisible al 2 y divisible con si mismo (4).

**El 4 no es primo por tiene mas de dos divisores.**

El Numero 5: Es divisible al 1 y divisible con si mismo (5).
El 5 es primo porque tiene solo estos dos divisores.

**Entonces cuando queremos encontraras los números primos hasta un numero x:**

Necesitamos que recorra desde el número 2 en adelante hasta el número X y calcule si es divisible al 1, y a si mismo. **Si tiene mas de estos divisores entonces no es primo.**

Lo que entiendo que estas buscando es: "Los números primos divisores de un numero entero"

```
def numerosPrimerosDeUnNumero(numero):
    lista = []
    for i in range(2, numero):
        if numero % i == 0:
            lista.append(i)
    return lista

print(numerosPrimerosDeUnNumero(5))
print(numerosPrimerosDeUnNumero(10))
print(numerosPrimerosDeUnNumero(15))
print(numerosPrimerosDeUnNumero(25))
print(numerosPrimerosDeUnNumero(847))
```

Lo que te devolver es de cada numero solicitado **sus números primos**.

```
[] # 5
[2, 5] # 10 
[3, 5]  # 15
[5] # 25
[7, 11, 77, 121] # 847
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: muchisimas gracias

Comment: @RodrigoGarciaBaqueroCano Pudiste utilizar esta función? Me pareció práctica para lo que querías hacer. Saludos.